# Clear cell google sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet on googlesheet where there is a lot of line and column.

I want clear the cell where there is the value 0 in the column B.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work, I'm not an expert of javascript :|

```
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  if(data == "0"){
    sheet.getRange('B:B').clearContent();
  }
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your mistake is that `data` is an array of arrays of values, and your comparison `data == "0"` assumes that `data` is a value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to clear the cell content for the cells of column B which has the value of "0". If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve values of "B:B".
- Retrieve ranges when the retrieved values are "0".
- Clear content for the retrieved ranges.

#### Modified script :

```
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getDisplayValues();
  var range = [];
  data.forEach(function(e, i){
    if (e[0] == "0") range.push("B" + (i + 1));
  });
  sheet.getRangeList(range).clearContent();
}
```

#### Reference :

- [getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

  - This method was added at April 11, 2018.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: perfect! Thank you :)