# Delete cell value based on values of another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need the cells in Column A cleared if the value in Column J = *

This asterisk found in Column J has been retrieved by using the following formula: `=iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "\*"), "")`

The contents of Column A will be put in manually and some examples are:

0701870 Jansen, , Peter PT (VH)(*) 10:00 - 15:00 5:00

07908765 Predo, , Bone PT2 (ZS)(^) 09:00 - 14:00 5:00

0715777 Tyk, , Manual PT2 09:00 - 14:00 5:00

Basically every string I copy into Column A that contains a `*` or a `^` I would like to be cleared. I have a working script that does this for me, however this deletes the entire row.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Floor 5a');
  var r = s.getRange('J:J');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='*')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

I honestly have no clue what im doing. Zero knowledge when it comes to scripts. I copy paste solutions of questions similar to mine and hope they work, which so far they've done, but now im stuck on this "issue". It now deletes all the contents of Column A. However I need it to only delete the content of A4 if J4 and/or A5 if J5 etc. has a `*` in it.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = sheet.getSheetByName('Floor 5a');
  var r = s.getRange('J:J');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='*')
      var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['A:A']);
  rangeList.clearContent();
};
```

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: Use a `RangeList`. Instead of deleting the row in your code, store the cell address in an array. Then feed that array to the RangeList constructor and clear the values.  You can then probably sort your sheet if you want to move all blanks to the bottom.

Comment: @tehhowch Could you give me an example? I have no idea how to do this. Here's a copy of my sheet, not sure if you need it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UFgm9g0v9jJyAsbOvziRMJ6Y2TxlpGLN_b1kc2O0R4I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you know `i`, don't you know the row you're working with? You state in your question you know which column you want to modify - row and column makes an address. To learn `RangeList`, you should read about it in the Apps Script developer site. When you have edited your question to try to achieve this, I will be happy to resolve the specific error holding you back.

Comment: @tehhowch I honestly have no clue what im doing, and I'd understand if you're unwilling to present the solution to me on a golden platter without me trying to learn. But this goes so far above my head, I'm unable to make any progress.

Comment: I'm getting somewhere, but it now deletes the entire Column A, or rather, the content of Column A.

Comment: Good! (that you are getting somewhere). This happens because you have only the single argument `'A:A'` in the constructor. You want to use an array, like `var addresses = [];`, and in your loop do `addresses.push(<conversion from i to cell address>);` Then you will have something like `['A3', 'A20', 'A51'...]`. After your loop is done, if there is anything in the array you used, then you make the rangelist and clear its content.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what im supposed to put into `addresses.push()`. Does this help me delete the content of A4 if J4 has a `*` in it?

Comment: Yep. For example, if `values` is J1:J, then `values[0][0]` is J1's value, and `values[i][0]` is J`i + 1` 's value. So you have `i`, you know the conversion between `i` and row, and you know the column.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me so far! You lost me with the whole array thing though. Honestly, I have no idea what the whole `i` thing is doing either.

Comment: Mixing formulas with scripts is a bad way. J is essentially a regex extract of A. Do you really need J or K? Can't you do the regex inside  the script itself? `getRange('A:A')`> check match for `^` or `*`> clear A. Also, you say "Copy into A", If so, a simple `onEdit` trigger should do the job. This might look complicated, if you're new, but it's the simplest way to do this. Review documentation (Event Objects, js Regex, clearContent,...)

Answer (score 0):

Found another script somewhere on the webs that seemed to do the trick:

```
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('J:J').getDisplayValues();
  var range = [];
  data.forEach(function(e, i){
    if (e[0] == "*") range.push("A" + (i + 1));
  });
  sheet.getRangeList(range).clearContent();
}
```

Found it here: [Clear cell google sheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166192/clear-cell-google-sheet-script)

Comment: So this script now succesfully checks J:J for `*` and deletes the A cell in the row it find a `*` Aka, if in J8 it finds a `*` it clears the content of A8. Question now is... can I add into this script, a way for it to also search K:K to do the same if it finds a `^`

Comment: Yes, you can. You'll have to alter how `data` is created and how you determine `if` you should store the cell address.